# Elastic beanstalk create environment FAILED YAML file does not exist

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've run into something weird so I thought I'd share it here in the hopes of helping someone else.

I used EB CLI to create an environment using `eb create` passing it additional arguments etc.

After a minute or so I received the following error:

```
2020-07-28 11:20:44    INFO    Build in progress. Phase: QUEUED Status: SUCCEEDED  
2020-07-28 11:20:44    INFO    Build in progress. Phase: PROVISIONING Status: SUCCEEDED  2020-07-28 11:20:44    ERROR   Build in progress. Phase: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE Status: FAILED YAML file does not exist  
ERROR: ServiceError - Finished processing application version app-5fd9-200728_211901 with status: FAILED.
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `buildspec.yml` to `buildspec.yaml` solved my problem.